# Rails 3 Apache & Mongrel

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, mongrel

colleagues.

**Here is what I have:**
Windows XP
Ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
Rails 3.1.0
Also I have installed mongrel server `gem install mongrel -v 1.2.0.pre2 --pre`
When I do rails s, mongrel starts (everything is ok)

But I want to use my RoR application via Apache 2.2, that is installed as service.
I decided that best way is to use Apache & Mongrel. Then I have installed mongrel_service `gem install mongrel_service`, and run mongrel as service `mongrel_rails service::install -N efiling_mongrel -c c:\sites\uplodify -p 3000 -e development -a 127.0.0.1`. Then I also setuped Apache...

When I started Apache as service and Mongrel as service, I see such picture:
1) my ruby proccess uses more than 50% of CPU resource
2) permanent growth log/mongrel.log file size
3) there are such errors in log/mongrel.log:

```
** Starting Mongrel listening at 127.0.0.1:3000  
** Starting Rails with development environment...  

C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)   
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'  
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'  
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'  
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'  
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:148:in `rails'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:116:in `block (2 levels) in run'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `call'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in `listener'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:102:in `block in run'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `call'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:86:in `new'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:86:in `run'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/lib/mongrel/command.rb:210:in `run'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-ingw32/bin/mongrel_rails:282:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
from C:/Ruby/Ruby192/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `<main>'
```

**Someone have any ideas?**

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with apache. Is there a particular reason that you want to use mongrel? Mongrel has not been updated for a while (1.5 years) and I do think it was developed when the version of rails was at 2.

Comment: No, there no. I need use strongly Windows environment. A gooogled for a long time, and I decided to use Mongrel because there is no other solutions ((

Comment: Do you have 'gem mongrel' in your Gemfile? This has nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: yes, I have line gem 'mongrel', '1.2.0.pre2'

Comment: you have a problem with dependencies. copy-paste your **Gemfile** and **Gemfile.lock**

Comment: Anton, I have done "bundle update" for updating gemfile.lock, but it does't help me

Comment: Why are you not using default server WEBrick? I am in windows environment with apache, but I am using rails just fine with WEBrick which is included in the rails. I don't understand why you are trying to install mongrel. Mongrel is old and doesn't get updated anymore.

Comment: user482594, Firstly, my aim was to run web server like a windows service. For this monrel is suitable, because it has mongrel_service.gem. Secondary, I did't want to launch own "rails s" for every application that I have.

Comment: I was unable to install and configure Mongrel in Windows XP. What I did finally was installing jRuby and running it in Tomcat. It worked great after some tweaks! If installing jRuby is an option please consider this.